# Cannot find namespace Microsoft.ReportingServices

Tags: .net, reporting-services

I changed my target framework from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0 Client Profile.

Now the namespaces Microsoft.ReportingServices and Microsoft.Reporting cannot be found.

> The type or namespace name 'Reporting' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

When I try to "Add Reference", I can't find them in the list.

I don't have any problems with the regular .NET 4.0 framework.

Is there anyway I can use these namespaces with .NET 4.0 Client Profile, or should I just use the regular .NET 4.0 framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Reporting Services assembly uses types outside of the Client Profile, so it itself cannot support the Client Profile. You should use the Full .NET Framework if you need access to the Reporting Services assembly.